# search form and data view in same page in yii

Tags: php, forms, yii, pagination

[image]
    I have search form as shown in pic and `Cgridview` to show the retrieved data in same page as.

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
            'id'=>'family-record-grid',
            'dataProvider'=>$dataProviderRegSum,
            'enableSorting' => false,

            //'enablePagination'=>false,

            'itemsCssClass'=>'tabchin',

            'columns'=>
            array(
array('header'=>'html',
        'id'=>'autoId',
        'class'=>'CCheckBoxColumn',

        'selectableRows' => '50',
        'headerTemplate'=>'<label>Select All{item}<span></span></label>',
        'value'=>'$data["familyid"].",".$data["PersonID"].",".$data["PaymentStatus"].",".$data["RegistrationStatus"].",".$data["SignUpCode"].",".$data["firstname"].",".$data["lastname"].",".$data["PaymentTxnDate"].",".$data["ChoiceCode"].",".$data["ChoiceLabel"].",".$data["ClassAssignment"]
        .",".$data["CreatedDate"].",".$data["Gender"].",".$data["age"].",".$data["schoolgrade"].",".$data["primarypersonid"].",".$data["PrimaryParentFirstName"].",".$data["PrimaryParentLastName"].",".str_replace(",",":",$data["primaryEmail"])
        .",".$data["SessionAssignment"].",".$data["SubClassAssignment"].",".$data["Reconcile"]',
        'htmlOptions'=>array("width"=>"40px;","align"=>"center"),

),
                     array(
                            'name'=>'PaymentDate',
                            'header'=>'Payment Date',
                            'value'=>'$data["PaymentTxnDate"]',
                            'type'=>'raw',
                            'htmlOptions'=>array("width"=>"100px","align"=>"left"),
                    ), 

array(
        'header'=>'Family ID',
        'name'=>'RegistrationID',
        'value' => 'CHtml::link($data["familyid"], Yii::app() ->createUrl("registration/familyregview",array("id"=>$data["familyid"])),array("class"=>"regfamily"))',

        'htmlOptions'=>array('style'=>'width:50px;text-align:center;'),
        'type'  => 'raw',
),
                    array(
                            'name'=>'PersonID',
                            'header'=>'Person ID',
                            'value'=>'$data["PersonID"].CHtml::hiddenField("Reg[]",$data["PersonID"])',
                            'type'=>'raw',
                            'htmlOptions'=>array("width"=>"50px;","align"=>"left"),
                    ),
                    array(
        'name'=>'FirstName',
        'header'=>'First Name',
        'value'=>'$data["firstname"]',
        'type'=>'raw',
        'htmlOptions'=>array("width"=>"100px;","align"=>"left"),
),
                                    array(
                                'name'=>'LastName',
                                'header'=>'Family Name',
                            'value'=>'$data["lastname"]',
                                'type'=>'raw',
                                'htmlOptions'=>array("width"=>"100px;","align"=>"left"),
                        ),
                    array(
                            'name'=>'Gender',
                            'header'=>'Gender',
                            'value'=>'$data["Gender"]',
                            'type'=>'raw',
                            'htmlOptions'=>array("width"=>"60px;","align"=>"left"),
                    ),
                    array(
                            'name'=>'age',
                            'header'=>'Age',
                            'value'=>'$data["age"]',
                            'type'=>'raw',
                            'htmlOptions'=>array("width"=>"50px;","align"=>"left",'title'=>'Age Calculate by Program SatrtDate'),
                    ),
                    array(
                            'name'=>'schoolgrade',
                            'header'=>'School Grade',
                            'value'=>'$data["schoolgrade"]',
                            'type'=>'raw',
                            'htmlOptions'=>array("width"=>"100px;","align"=>"left"),
                    ),
                    array(
                            'name'=>'primarypersonid',
                            'header'=>'Primary Person ID',
                            'value'=>'$data["primarypersonid"]',
                            'type'=>'raw',
                            'htmlOptions'=>array("width"=>"100px;","align"=>"left"),
                    ),
                    array(
                            'name'=>'PrimaryParentFirstName',
                            'header'=>'Primary First Name',
                            'value'=>'$data["PrimaryParentFirstName"]',
                            'type'=>'raw',
                            'htmlOptions'=>array("width"=>"100px;","align"=>"left"),
                    ),
                    array(
                            'name'=>'PrimaryParentLastName',
                            'header'=>'Primary Last Name',
                            'value'=>'$data["PrimaryParentLastName"]',
                            'type'=>'raw',
                            'htmlOptions'=>array("width"=>"100px;","align"=>"left"),
                    ),
                    array(
                            'name'=>'primaryEmail',
                            'header'=>'E-Mail',
                            'value'=>'$data["primaryEmail"]',
                            'type'=>'raw',
                            'htmlOptions'=>array("width"=>"100px;","align"=>"left"),
                    ),
                    array(
                            'name'=>'Reconcile',
                            'header'=>'Reconcile',
                            'value'=>'$data["Reconcile"]',
                            'type'=>'raw',
                            'htmlOptions'=>array("width"=>"40px;","align"=>"left"),
                    ),
                    //primaryEmail
                    array(
                            'header'=>'Payment',
                            'name'=>'Payemnt',
                            'value' => 'CHtml::link(CHtml::image("img/payment_history.png", "Delete", array("title"=>"Payment History","style"=>"width:32px;height:32px;")),
                            Yii::app() ->createUrl("registration/paymentregview",array("id"=>$data["familyid"])),array("class"=>"regpay"))',

                            'htmlOptions'=>array('style'=>'width:50px;text-align:center;'),
                            'type'  => 'raw',
                    ),
                    array(
                            'name'=>'CreatedDate',
                            'header'=>'Date Created',
                            'value'=>'$data["CreatedDate"]',
                            'type'=>'raw',
                            'htmlOptions'=>array("width"=>"80px;","align"=>"left"),
                    ),




),

));
```

I wanna clear again that
So I have search form as shown in pic and the `Cgridview` in same page.

when the search button is clicked, the data should be retrieved and displayed the `cgridview` with pagination. How it can be achieved? Please help me.

I have submit button code as

```
$count = Yii::app()->db->createCommand('SELECT COUNT(familyid) FROM (' . $sql2 . ') as count_alias')->queryScalar();

    $rawData = Yii::app()->db->createCommand($sql2);

    $dataProviderRegSum = new CSqlDataProvider($rawData, array(
            'keyField' => 'familyid',
            //'pagination'=>false,
            /* 'pagination' => array(
             'pageSize' => Yii::app()->user->getState( 'pageSize', Yii::app()->params[ 'defaultPageSize' ] ),PaymentTxnDate
            ), */
            'totalItemCount' => $count,
            /* 'sort'=>array(
             //'defaultOrder' => 'CreatedDate desc',
                    'defaultOrder' => 'PaymentTxnDate asc',
                    'attributes'=>array(
                            'RegistrationID'=>array(
                                    'asc'=>'familyid',
                                    'desc'=>'familyid DESC',
                            ),
                            'FirstName'=>array(
                                    'asc'=>'firstname',
                                    'desc'=>'firstname DESC',
                            ),
                            'LastName'=>array(
                                    'asc'=>'lastname',
                                    'desc'=>'lastname DESC',
                            ),
                            'CreatedDate'=>array(
                                    'asc'=>'CreatedDate',
                                    'desc'=>'CreatedDate DESC',
                            ),
                            'EmailedDate'=>array(
                                    'asc'=>'EamiledDate',
                                    'desc'=>'EamiledDate DESC',
                            ),



                    ),),

    */              'pagination'=>array('pageSize'=>20)
    ));
```

here `$sql2` is my query.

how to pass this `$dataProviderRegSum` to same view and show in `cgridview` with pagination.

Comment: I don't think anyone can help you without knowing the relevant part(s) of your code. Please have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: dont you understand the question..

Comment: There isn't even a question in your post, have you read the how to ask guide?

Comment: I need suggestion for problem not the suggestions for how to ask....

Comment: Nobody knows how to solve your problem because there is no code. The community won't do your research here. If you would read the guide, you would understand that nobody should answer your question, even if they know what the problem is to keep this platform clean.

Comment: what happend @P0rnflake

Answer (score 0):

I will give you one example. Try that way. May this will help you.

In view,

```
<div class="page-content">
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-3 pull-right"> <br>
            <input type="text"  id="search" class="form-control" placeholder="Search..."><br>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <?php
            /**
             * Listing of all employees
             */
            $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
                'id' => 'employee-grid',
                'dataProvider' => $model->search(),
                'selectableRows' => 1,
                'ajaxUpdate' => true,
                'hideHeader' => false,
                'template' => "{items}\n{pager}",
                'enableHistory' => false,
                'enableSorting' => false,
                'cssFile' => Yii::app()->baseUrl . '/css/grid.css',
                'htmlOptions' => array('class' => 'grid-view table-responsive'),
                'columns' => array(
                    array(
                        'header' => 'Sl.No.',
                        'value' => '$this->grid->dataProvider->pagination->currentPage * $this->grid->dataProvider->pagination->pageSize + ($row+1)',
                        'htmlOptions' => array('width' => '5%'),
                    ),
                    array(
                        'header' => 'Employee Code',
                        'value' => '$data->employeecode',
                    ),
                    array(
                        'header' => 'Employee Name',
                        'value' => '$data->firstname." ".$data->lastname',
                    ),
                    array(
                        'header' => 'Department',
                        'value' => '$data->department->department_name',
                    ),
                    array(
                        'header' => 'Designation',
                        'value' => '$data->designation->designation_name',
                    ),
                    array(
                        'header' => 'Email',
                        'value' => '$data->email',
                    ),
                    array('class' => 'CButtonColumn',
                        'header' => 'Manage',
                        'template' => ' {view} {delete}',
                        'htmlOptions' => array('width' => '10%'),
                        'buttons' => array(
                            'view' => array(
                                'label' => '',
                                'imageUrl' => '',
                                'options' => array('class' => 'glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open'),
                            ),
                            'delete' => array(
                                'label' => '',
                                'imageUrl' => '',
                                'options' => array('class' => 'glyphicon glyphicon-remove'),
                            ),
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
            ));
            ?>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
 <script>
  $("input").keyup(function () {

   $('#employee-grid').yiiGridView('update', {
       data: {search: $('#search').val()}
   });
   return false;
   });
 </script>
```

In model change search function,

```
  public function search() {
    // @todo Please modify the following code to remove attributes that should not be searched.

    $criteria = new CDbCriteria;

    $criteria->order = 'staffid DESC';
    $financialyear = Financialyear::model()->findByAttributes(array('status' => '1')); //! $financialyear stores activated financial year details
    $searchterm = empty($searchterm) ? trim(Yii::app()->request->getParam('search')) : $searchterm;
    $criteria->with = array('department', 'designation');
    $searchterm = htmlspecialchars($searchterm, ENT_QUOTES);
    if (!empty($searchterm)) {
        $criteria->addCondition(' t.employeecode like "' . $searchterm . '%" OR
              t.firstname like "' . $searchterm . '%" OR
              t.email like "' . $searchterm . '%" OR
            designation.designation_name like "' . $searchterm . '%" OR
          department.department_name like "' . $searchterm . '%" AND
              t.status = "0" ');
    } else {
        $criteria->condition = 't.status = "0"';
    }

    return new CActiveDataProvider($this, array(
        'criteria' => $criteria,
        'pagination' => array(
            'pagesize' => 25,
        )
    ));
}
```

This code working nicely for me. So please go through it.

Comment: Please refer above codes, in that one script is there. Using that send data from text box to search function. that was keyup method